# setting up offsets in formula range to avoid overrighting

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take the following code and structure it in such a way that it will loop through all items on the list and create a new section for each iteration, skipping a row.

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,1,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,2,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A6").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,3,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A7").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,4,FALSE)&"", ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,5,FALSE)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,6,FALSE))"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("C4").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,7,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("C5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,8,FALSE)"
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("C6").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,9,FALSE)"
    Next row
```

So instead of copying over A4-C6 (as defined), it would create the next set A9-C11, then A14-C16, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach, I've just done the first one

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To 50 Step 5 'change upper limit as applicable
    For Each Row In Rng.Rows
        wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A4").Offset(i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,1,FALSE)"
        'etc
    Next Row
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: No dice.  It just keeps copying over with the same data.  But I think that might be my fault in my explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish... each iteration has to accomplish two things.  The vlookup has to look to the next row (so the first time it runs `VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,1,FALSE)` then the next is `VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A2,Customers,1,FALSE)` and so on.  each run should copy down as I indicated in the original post. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: I didn't change the formula. Do you mean the formula in A4 should be `VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,1,FALSE)` and the formula in A9 should be `VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A2,Customers,1,FALSE)`?

Comment: you are correct.  I've solved the first part of my problem with auto increment of the lookup value, now I have to wrap that in a loop that will step 5 rows for each lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
Sub Report()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim j As Long

    Set rng = wsCustomerList.Range("A1:A" & LastRow(wsCustomerList))
    j = 1
    For Each row In rng.Rows
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,1,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,2,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,3,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,4,FALSE)&"", ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,5,FALSE)&"" ""&VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,6,FALSE))"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,7,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,8,FALSE)"
            wsCustomerReportCard.Range("E6").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!R" & j & "C1,Customers,9,FALSE)"
            j = j + 1
        Next row

End Sub
```